# How to Send Graphs/Pie Charts Via Email

Tags: c#, vb.net, dataset, report, reportviewer

I am looking to make a VB.net program that fills a dataset, and then emails the results.  However, I'd like the results to be emailed in Graphs and or Pie Charts.  and be placed at specific spots in the email body.  Can anyone provide me with some options to get started?  I'm able to send the info in html table form, however the data is very boring.

Here is what i'm currently doing to build the table:

```
Dim open = _
            <html>
                <body>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr><th>Description</th><th> Test </th></tr>
                        <%= From opentime In Me.test_Dataset.OpenTime.AsEnumerable _
                            Select <tr><td>Open Time</td>
                                       <td><%= opentime.dtTimeIn.ToString("hh:mm tt") %></td>
                                       <td width="50"><%= opentime.sFirstName %></td></tr> %>
```

I then send the email doing this:

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
            Net.NetworkCredential("login", "password") 'Assign the network credentials
            SmtpServer.Port = 25 'Assign the SMTP Port
            SmtpServer.Host = "10.0.1.1" 'Assign the Server IP
            mail = New MailMessage() 'Starts a mail message
            mail.From = New MailAddress("reports@reports.com") 'Sets the "FROM" address
            mail.To.Add("user1@user.com") 'Sets the "To" address
            mail.Subject = "report "
            mail.IsBodyHtml = True
            mail.Body = open.ToString()
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

Comment: See [Writing The Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "inline CSS". or make a image of the graph and embed it into the e-mail body

Comment: If you want to generate an image of a chart we make a command line tool for charting sql queries that may help http://www.sqldashboards.com/sqlchart